# error in import styled-components to components React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, styled-components

I imported `styled-components` to component.
`import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';`
the error 
`TypeError: Object(...) is not a function 
 var ThemeContext = createContext();` occurred.

my `package.js`

```
"dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  },
```

code of component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';
import FlyingObjectBase from './FlyingObjectBase';
import FlyingObjectTop from './FlyingObjectTop';

const FlyingObject = props => (
    <g>
      <FlyingObjectBase position={props.position} />
      <FlyingObjectTop position={props.position} />
    </g>
  );

  FlyingObject.propTypes = {
    position: PropTypes.shape({
      x: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      y: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    }).isRequired,
  };

  export default FlyingObject;
```

error in console

```
bundle.js:38257 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:38257)
    at Object../node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js (bundle.js:39107)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:679)
    at fn (bundle.js:89)
    at Object../src/components/FlyingObject.jsx (bundle.js:41736)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:679)
    at fn (bundle.js:89)
    at Object../src/components/Canvas.jsx (bundle.js:41498)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:679)
    at fn (bundle.js:89)
    at Object../src/App.js (bundle.js:41128)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:679)
    at fn (bundle.js:89)
    at Object../src/containers/Game.js (bundle.js:42377)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:679)
    at fn (bundle.js:89)
    at Object../src/index.js (bundle.js:42462)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:679)
    at fn (bundle.js:89)
    at Object.0 (bundle.js:42872)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:679)
    at bundle.js:725
    at bundle.js:728
```

the index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './containers/App';
import reducer from './reducers';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';



/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
const store = createStore(
  reducer, /* preloadedState, */
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
);
/* eslint-enable */

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

What is the solution?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please provide more code and how you are trying to use `styled-components` so we can see what you might be doing wrong?

Comment: @trevor i added whole of code components.thanks you.

Comment: There isn't enough context here with this code to figure out what is going on unfortunately.

Comment: You need to show the code where you use ` var ThemeContext = createContext();` and error is occuring

Comment: Usually this error is related to not properly importing/exporting from your files. Double check all your files and ensure you are exporting and using the proper imports.

Comment: I added code from ```index.js```

Comment: I think my react version is low
```"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0"```
**in Styled Components/FAQs**
Make sure your application is using react >= 16.3; internally we are using the new React.forwardRef API and new context APIs if you wish to try and polyfill for older React version support.

I will try it

Comment: it's not my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is solved [@garetmckinley](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/7897#issuecomment-419672087) Thanks.

> works fine if you install v3